# Java.lang.NullPointerException when adding action Listener to button?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Never posted here before but im not sure why it isn't working with this code but is working in another. Oh in using `BlueJ` and it's saying the `calcButton.addActionListener(handler);` is the error.

```
public class JoesAutoGUI extends JPanel
{
protected RoutineService routineServices;
protected NonroutineService nonroutineServices;
protected SummaryPanel summarypanel;

protected JTabbedPane tabbs;

protected JPanel title;
protected JPanel charges;
protected JPanel summary;
protected JPanel buttonPanel;

protected JLabel titlePanel;

protected JButton calcButton;
protected JButton exitButton;

protected ImageIcon car;


public JoesAutoGUI()
{
    //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tabbs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

    buildButtonPanel();
    buildTitlePanel();

    JPanel charges = new JPanel(); 
    tabbs.addTab("Charges", null, charges, "Charges calculator");
    charges.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
    charges.add(titlePanel,                                   BorderLayout.NORTH);  
    charges.add( routineServices = new RoutineService(),      BorderLayout.WEST);
    charges.add(nonroutineServices = new NonroutineService(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    charges.add(buttonPanel,                                  BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel summary = new JPanel();
    tabbs.addTab("Summary", null, summary,"sum summary");
    summary.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
    summary.add(summarypanel = new SummaryPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

   add(tabbs);
}


private void buildButtonPanel()
{
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    JoesAutoHandler handler = new JoesAutoHandler(this);
    calcButton.addActionListener(handler); <-------error here?
    exitButton.addActionListener(handler);

    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Calculate Charges"));
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Exit"));
    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel(""));
}

private void buildTitlePanel()
{
    //build the label
    titlePanel = new JLabel();

    //set the layout for label
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //create the icon
    car = new ImageIcon("images/car.jpg");

    //choose the the lable and icon used in the label
    titlePanel = new JLabel("Joe's Automotives", car, JLabel.CENTER );

    //add the titel panel
    add(titlePanel);
}
}
```

not to sure if anyone can help without the rest of the code?

Comment: You haven't initialized `calcButton`. It is `null`.

Comment: well then this is awkward... didnt notice

Comment: Could have specified at what line the error occurred, but if it's already solved, then it's no point :)

Comment: i did say where the error was :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create an object of `JButton`  like `JButton calcButton =new JButton();`

In this line `protected JButton calcButton;` you have just created a reference but you have not created object anywhere